# Modal or Non Modal functionality on UX Stack exchange portal - Behaviour Confusion

Tags: usability, interaction-design, design-patterns, usability-testing, modal-windows

I was going through the profile section of the stack exchange site today and i found an interesting behaviour of modal window.

[image]

As far as what I have observed in various articles and design systems

1. The **modals** are supposed to block the user flow and do no allow user to interact with the background of the modal while
2. The **non modals** allow their movement on the screen and allow the user to interact with the background.

I am confused if this is deliberate use of such interaction or there is something else that I am missing here. Anyone with any references to this behaviour that could help me understand this UI element better is appreciable.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is, it's a bug. Since the interaction works according to the principles of a non-modal window, and the design is made according to the modal.

In a nutshell, if we cover the background with a dark layer, then we do not want the user to interact with it until they do the main action in the modal window.

There are also types of non-modal windows. In these windows, we give the user the ability to interact with the [content below them.](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/modal-nonmodal-dialog/#:%7E:text=Nonmodal%20windows%20are%20useful%20when) The simplest example is Gmail.

[image]